# How to create an URL with variable subdomain like www.userspecified.example.com?

Tags: url, subdomain

I have noticed many websites (e.g. quora) create URL in which there is a userspecific part before the domain name. For example is Quora blog -

`www.BLOGNAME.quora.com`

I know that I can add a fixed subdomain in the DNS CNAME as shown [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81246/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-my-domain-name)

My question is how do I make it variable for different users? The BLOGNAME part of the quora url id different for differnt blogs.

Comment: are you asking how to configure subdomains of `quora.com` or how to set up a subdomain in general?

Comment: @ctt I know how to create a subdomain. I am asking how to create "dynamic" subdomain like Quora.com. If you create a blog names "xyz" on quora the url for the blog appears as "xyz.quora.com" and it is true for all blogs. It is obviously not done manually. How is it done? any idea?

Comment: Setup a wildcard CNAME record (with rdata `*`)  that points to an load balancer on foo.com. Configure your load balancer to terminate SSL with either a wildcard cert, or to dynamically choose a cert based on the requested host.  Have your blog platform's backend determine the target blog for each request based on the HTTP `Host` header.